# R: keep c2 values long, use c1 values as column names

Tags: r

I have a data frame of over 3000 obs. that looks similar to this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  letter = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=4),
  numbers = rep(seq(1,1.75, by=0.25), 3)
  )
dat
# letter numbers
# 1       A    1.00
# 2       A    1.25
# 3       A    1.50
# 4       A    1.75
# 5       B    1.00
# 6       B    1.25
# 7       B    1.50
# 8       B    1.75
# 9       C    1.00
# 10      C    1.25
# 11      C    1.50
# 12      C    1.75
```

I would like to rearrange this data frame so that it looks like:

```
# A    B    C
# 1 1.00 1.00 1.00
# 2 1.25 1.25 1.25
# 3 1.50 1.50 1.50
# 4 1.75 1.75 1.75
```

without having to manually hard code all 3,000 observations.

Out of all of the tools that I have - potentially incorrectly - tried so far (reshape, split, group_split, mutate %>% split %>% unnest, pivot_wider, and dcast) split gives the closest output to what I am trying to achieve (see below), but I am not sure how to index specific columns of a data frame nested within a data frame, and I am unsure of how to recombine the individual data frames without joining them, i.e. I want to keep all values independent from one another under each letter.

```
spldf <- split(dat, dat$letter)
spldf

# $A
# letter numbers
# 1      A    1.00
# 2      A    1.25
# 3      A    1.50
# 4      A    1.75
# 
# $B
# letter numbers
# 5      B    1.00
# 6      B    1.25
# 7      B    1.50
# 8      B    1.75
# 
# $C
# letter numbers
# 9       C    1.00
# 10      C    1.25
# 11      C    1.50
# 12      C    1.75
```

I have been looking through S.O. for 2 days now, and have not seen a question that was similar enough for me to replicate it. I appreciate any assistance with this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of elements for the 'letter' column is same, we can use `unstack` as well from `base R`

```
unstack(dat, numbers ~ letter)
```

-output

```
#    A    B    C
#1 1.00 1.00 1.00
#2 1.25 1.25 1.25
#3 1.50 1.50 1.50
#4 1.75 1.75 1.75
```

---

But, if the data is really big, chances of having unequal length is greater.  In that case, we need a sequence column to make sure that if there are lesser length, it can be filled with `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
dat %>% 
    mutate(rn = rowid(letter)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = letter, values_from = numbers) %>% 
    select(-rn)
```

Comment: This worked beautifully once I reduced my actual data frame to 2 columns as it is in the example above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(dat),rowid(letter)~letter,value.var = "numbers")[,-1]
```

gives

```
      A    B    C
1: 1.00 1.00 1.00
2: 1.25 1.25 1.25
3: 1.50 1.50 1.50
4: 1.75 1.75 1.75
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this within the tidyverse framework but you will need to add an id variable marking the sequence of numbers within letters.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  letter = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=4),
  numbers = rep(seq(1,1.75, by=0.25), 3)
)

dat%>%  group_by(letter)%>%
  mutate(id=1:n()) %>%  
  pivot_wider(id_cols=id, 
              names_from = letter,
              values_from=numbers) %>% 
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>       A     B     C
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1     1     1   
#> 2  1.25  1.25  1.25
#> 3  1.5   1.5   1.5 
#> 4  1.75  1.75  1.75
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>